# ChartJS legend is not included in image if is a custom legend

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

As the title says the custom legend of a ChartJS is not included in the image that i am saving from the canvas and that is probably also the problem, because the legend is not part of the canvas anymore is not included in the image. Is there any way to include the custom legend in the canvas?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZGyNW

```
var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('mychart'), {
type: 'pie',
animation:{
    animateScale:true
},
data: {
    labels: visitData,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Visitor',
        data: visitorData,
        backgroundColor: [
            "#a2d6c4",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#3e8787",
            "#579aac",
            "#7dcfe8",
            "#b3dfe7",
        ]
    }]
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: false,
    legendCallback: function(chart) {
        var legendHtml = [];
        legendHtml.push('<ul>');
        var item = chart.data.datasets[0];
        for (var i=0; i < item.data.length; i++) {
            legendHtml.push('<li>');
            legendHtml.push('<span class="chart-legend" style="background-color:' + item.backgroundColor[i] +'"></span>');
            legendHtml.push('<span class="chart-legend-label-text">' + item.data[i] + ' person - '+chart.data.labels[i]+' times</span>');
            legendHtml.push('</li>');
        }

        legendHtml.push('</ul>');
        legendHtml.push('<table border="1" width="600"><tr><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>Island Trading</td><td>Helen Bennett</td><td>UK</td></tr><tr><td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td><td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td><td>Canada</td></tr><tr><td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td><td>Giovanni Rovelli</td><td>Italy</td></tr></table>');
        return legendHtml.join("");
    },
    tooltips: {
         enabled: true,
         mode: 'label',
         callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var indice = tooltipItem.index;
                return data.datasets[0].data[indice] + " person visited " + data.labels[indice] + ' times';
            }
         }
     },
}
});
```

`$('#my-legend-con').html(myChart.generateLegend());`

Comment: No, custom legend is HTML and can't be part of a canvas, the chart container.

Comment: You can try libs like Html2Canvas to capture HTML parts as canvas.